# Shotwell refuses to run after upgrade to Zesty

Tags: upgrade, shared-library, shotwell

I’ve been having trouble getting Shotwell 0.26.1 to run since upgrading to Zesty. Running from a terminal, I get the following error message:

```
shotwell: error while loading shared libraries: libraw.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Running locate for libraw.so finds libraw.so.16, so it would seem that Shotwell is looking for an earlier version of libraw.

Suggestions welcome. Many thanks.